# Event backgrid:rendered does not work - Backgrid.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, event-handling, backbone-events, backgrid

I try to use [Backgrid.js](http://backgridjs.com/). I have some grid (I just take [server-mode example](https://github.com/backbone-paginator/backbone.paginator/blob/master/examples/server-mode.html)).

This library successfully built a grid for me. But I want map some cells to their equivalent. For example, I have `"region_id"` column. I want map `region_id -> region_name`. To complete this task, I subscribed to the event `backgrid:rendered`.

```
var grid = new Backgrid.Grid({
  /////

  collection: issues
});

grid.on('backgrid:rendered', function(g) { 
    $('tr').each(function (i, row) {

        var $row = $(row);

        console.log("Q");
    });
});
```

But I get a fail. There is no iterating over rows of my table. But these rows exist in table. What is the problem?

Comment: I created a small jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dethariel/gtt68z6d/). Can you please edit it so that the error is reproduced? Because currently I see the event being fired.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that both of the following is true:

- you make a call to `grid.render()` method
- `issues` variable refers to non-empty collection at the time of rendering

Comment: Both of these statements are true. The process of render is successful. Anyway, I solved my problem, using some workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Backgrid fires the rendered event before the header, footer and the table itself are actually on the screen. 
So when your event gets triggered there are no rows in DOM yet.
I solved my problem by calling my code after the 
grid.render().$el
statement. After this table should be in DOM. At least header row was and that was all I needed.

I am stuck with old version of Backgrid 0.2.6. So bare in mind that my answer is from that perspective.